# php: the best way to store data of arbitrary html elements in html to pass this data to innerHTML of elements on a HTML-page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

For example I have such string in php:

```
$str='<img title="title of image" src="../somepic.gif" alt="some pic image" class="someclass" style="somestiles" onload="alert(this)" />';
//it can be anything: '<br>123<P><script>' or '123</script>' (even with newlines \r and \n and other special symbols)
```

And I need it to show only after click:

```
<?php 
echo'<div>
  <textarea onclick="this.parentNode.innerHTML=this.value">',htmlspecialchars($str),'</textarea>
</div>'; 
?>
```

As we can see, js replaces texarea element with what was stored in $str variable and placed in "<textarea>" value as text.

I need to know how to achieve this **without using textarea elements** for storing data for JS. 
(now i'm using hidden textareas, but I doubt that such method is correct)

Comment: with jQuery this becomes an almost trivial task.  You will need to wait for a better answer using just bare javascript tho.

Comment: Why don't you just use `display: none;` and `display: block` switches as the code is not created dynamically.

Comment: @Sirko: in $str can be, for example, '<br><br><br>' tags, or '<script>var d='risch'; alert(d);</script><p>' or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the HTML as a (properly-escaped) string:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
    html = "<img src='http://placekitten.com/100/100' onclick='alert(1);' />";

if (foo.addEventListener) {
    foo.addEventListener("click", setInner, false);
} else if(foo.attachEvent) {
    foo.attachEvent("onclick", setInner);
}

function setInner () {
    foo.innerHTML = html;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UAL8P/

Comment: what if there are newlines (\r\n or \n or \r) in $str?

Comment: @EL2002 Remove them. They aren't necessary when you're dealing with HTML anyway, unless you're doing some type of preformatting.

Comment: for example $str="<textarea>1\r\n2\n3\r4\r\n5</textarea>" and result will be corrupted

Comment: @EL2002 And when you place that in your HTML, it is no different than `12345`, so you might as well remove the line-breaks.

Comment: that's important for stored data to be exact the same as the source data.

Comment: @EL2002 Not when you're spitting it out into HTML - newlines in the source aren't preserved unless the markup styled in such a way that source-formatting is preserved.

Comment: @EL2002 On second thought, after doing a quick test it's clear that JavaScript variables are just fine with `\r\n` instances. No worries there. I even modified the string in the example above and sure enough it worked just fine, even preserving the format in the source.